# how to perform an heavy database related task in laravel that consume more than 30 seconds

Tags: laravel, task

I'm developing a binary multilevel marketing system in Laravel, at the registration time there we have to perform a task to entries for many types of bonus for each parent nodes of a new user. This task is time-consuming.

No one user want to see buffering and task taking more than 30 second that is not the right way.

I want to run this mechanism in the background and send a success message that your account created successfully.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers) that trigger [queued jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues).

After the user does an action on a model, the observers create queued jobs in the background. While the queue is being processed the user can continue working.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Now using queue Jobs and observers I can optimize the performance of the application and improve performance.

Answer (score 2):

either implement laravel job and queues or use https://github.com/spatie/async. 
you can invoke sub processes to make your task

```
use Spatie\Async\Pool;

$pool = Pool::create();

foreach ($things as $thing) {
    $pool->add(function () use ($thing) {
        // Do a thing
    })->then(function ($output) {
        // Handle success
    })->catch(function (Throwable $exception) {
        // Handle exception
    });
}

$pool->wait();
```